# Encrypt and decrypt with password in Android

Tags: android, encryption

I have a cryption class like this:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
 * Usage:
 *

 * String crypto = SimpleCrypto.encrypt(masterpassword, cleartext)
 * ...
 * String cleartext = SimpleCrypto.decrypt(masterpassword, crypto)
 *

 * @author ferenc.hechler
 */

public class SimpleCrypto {

    public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
        return toHex(result);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
        return new String(result);
    }

    private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed(seed);
        kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
        return raw;
    }


    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
        return encrypted;
    }

    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }

    public static String toHex(String txt) {
        return toHex(txt.getBytes());
    }
    public static String fromHex(String hex) {
        return new String(toByte(hex));
    }

    public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
        int len = hexString.length()/2;
        byte[] result = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
        return result;
    }

    public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
        if (buf == null)
            return "";
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            appendHex(result, buf[i]);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
        sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
    }
}
```

And here is my activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="xmaxsoft.delsifremax.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="tv1"
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:background="#120b0b"
        android:textColor="#f75555"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="tvText"
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:background="#120b0b"
        android:textColor="#f75555"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="tvTextEnc"
        android:id="@+id/tvTextEnc"
        android:background="#120b0b"
        android:textColor="#f75555"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="encrypt"
        android:id="@+id/btnEncrypt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etPw"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnEncrypt"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnEncrypt"
        android:background="#110f0f"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="etPw"
        android:textColor="#28bf25" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Decrypt"
        android:id="@+id/btnDecrypt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTextEnc"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/etPw"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/etPw" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="tvTextDec"
        android:id="@+id/tvTextDec"
        android:background="#120b0b"
        android:textColor="#f75555"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnDecrypt"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my MainActivity:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv1;
    TextView tvText;
    TextView tvTextEnc;
    TextView tvTextDec;
    Button btnEncrypt;
    Button btnDecrypt;
    EditText etPw;

    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvText);
        tvTextEnc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTextEnc);
        tvTextDec = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTextDec);
        btnEncrypt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEncrypt);
        btnDecrypt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDecrypt);
        etPw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPw);

        btnEncrypt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String normalText = tvText.getText().toString().trim();
                String normalTextEnc = "";
                String seedValue = etPw.getText().toString().trim();
                try {

                    normalTextEnc = SimpleCrypto.encrypt(seedValue,normalText.trim());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                tvTextEnc.setText(normalTextEnc.toString().trim());
            }
        });

        btnDecrypt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String normalTextEnc = tvTextEnc.getText().toString().trim();
                String normalTextDec = "";
                String seedValue = etPw.getText().toString().trim();
                try {

                    normalTextDec = SimpleCrypto.decrypt(seedValue, normalTextEnc.trim());
                    tvTextDec.setText(normalTextDec.toString().trim());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    tvTextDec.setText(e.toString());
                }
            }
        });

        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://xmaxsoft.delsifremax/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://xmaxsoft.delsifremax/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

I can encrypt string but i can't decrypt encrypted string again. Why? What is wrong with this code? I get "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException:pad block corrupted" error with that.

Comment: Try with out timing text,

Comment: You're using wrong Cipher padding. Replace AES with AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding in Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); in both encrypt and decrypt methods

Comment: Also make sure that the value of raw is same for encrypt and decrypt method. If they're not same, you'll never be able to decrypt your encrypted string.

Comment: Jitendra what do you mean?

Comment: Yasir i tried that you said and it didn't successful. How can i encrypt string with password and decrypt again with same password?

Comment: For now, don't use getRawKey method and for raw just use seed.getBytes in both methods to check whether you're able to encrypt and decrypt the same string. Your getRawKey method generate random seed everything which is different from the one with which you encrypted the string

Comment: Yasir how can i do that?

Comment: can anyone advice encrypt and decrypt method or class like that?

Answer (score 0):

I have this class that use password and salt to encrypt and decrypt some String:

```
public class Crypto {
    private static String IV = "IV_VALUE_16_BYTE";
    private static String PASSWORD = "some-hash-password";
    private static String SALT = "some-hash-salt";

    public static String encryptAndEncode(String raw) {
        try {
            Cipher c = getCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
            byte[] encryptedVal = c.doFinal(getBytes(raw));
            String s = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedVal, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return s;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new RuntimeException(t);
        }
    }

    public static String decodeAndDecrypt(String encrypted) throws Exception {
        byte[] decodedValue = Base64.decode(getBytes(encrypted),Base64.DEFAULT);
        Cipher c = getCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decodedValue);
        return new String(decValue);
    }

    private String getString(byte[] bytes) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    }

    private static byte[] getBytes(String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return str.getBytes("UTF-8");
    }

    private static Cipher getCipher(int mode) throws Exception {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] iv = getBytes(IV);
        c.init(mode, generateKey(), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        return c;
    }

    private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        char[] password = PASSWORD.toCharArray();
        byte[] salt = getBytes(SALT);

        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 128);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        byte[] encoded = tmp.getEncoded();
        return new SecretKeySpec(encoded, "AES");
    }

}
```

to encrypt:

```
Crypto.encryptAndEncode("String_to_encrypt");
```

to decrypt:

```
Crypto.decodeAndDecrypt("String_encrypted");
```

Hope it helps!